# How to generate TWILIO_SDK_STARTER_SERVER_URL for android app

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

Hi I am doing video chat using Twilio.I am follow https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android link for development.I am facing problem for generate TWILIO_SDK_STARTER_SERVER_URL.My demo app running successfully but video call not establish,showing "Set a valid sdk starter server url".So can you Please help me how to generate "TWILIO_SDK_STARTER_SERVER_URL".